# Order articles by date and by votes using acts_as_votable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to create a rating system in my app. I decided to use acs_as_votable gem, as it seems to be a powerful and popular gem that offers voting functionality.

I want to make my articles votable, and that works.

However, I would like to sort articles based on publishing date, and then sort the articles published on the same day by number of upvotes.

I think the question is clear, but let me illustrate by example.

Let's say Article , Article  and Article 3 are published today and they have 5, 3, 10 upvotes, respectively.

Article 4, article 5 and article 6 are articles posted yesterday and they have 1,2 and 3 upvotes respectively.

Sorted articles should look like

```
Article 3 (10 upvotes)
Article 1 (5 upvotes)
Article 2 (3 upvotes)
Article 6 (3 upvotes)
Article 5 (2 upvotes)
Article 4 (1 upvote)
```

Ideally, I would like to extract the date before all articles posted on the same day (something like on producthunt) so it would loo like this, but this is optional.

```
**9/22/2015**
Article 3 (10 upvotes)
Article 1 (5 upvotes)
Article 2 (3 upvotes)
**9/21/2015**
Article 6 (3 upvotes)
Article 5 (2 upvotes)
Article 4 (1 upvote)
```

Simple sorting by upvotes was solved here:
[acts_as_votable ordering by upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103738/acts-as-votable-ordering-by-upvotes)

But how do I sort by two criteria: date and upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you implement caching on `acts_as_votable` as documented on the posting you referenced, you should be able to just do something like:

```
Article.order(cached_votes_total: :desc, published_at: :desc)
```

Rails will do the trick for you. I found this posting helpful: [Ruby on Rails: how do I sort with two columns using ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587776/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-sort-with-two-columns-using-activerecord)

Comment: Just an update:

The order should actually be:
order('cast(created_at as date) desc, cached_votes_up desc')